# Fixed columns and scroll horizontal and vertical

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Is it possible to keep the first two columns fixed in a grid and scroll from the third column (horizontal) and keep all the headers fixed when scrolling vertical.
I'm trying to use DevExpress to do that. Do you have any ideas because I saw some different documentation, but it does not describe what I need.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6302/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Table-View/Fixed-Columns-and-Bands

https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/Scrolling.aspx

Comment: Can you provide current code example to explain what you want to do? Also you're using MVC tag, probably the scrolling thing related to `GridView` HTML helper.

Comment: Yes. you can make fixed column for devexpress grid ([Refer Fixed Column](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/FixedColumns.aspx))